# Windows Phone TextBlock aligment

Tags: windows-phone-8

In ListBox with ItemTemplate second TextBlock **not align** to right.

In design mode second TextBlock **align** to right

```xml
    <ListBox >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock 
                        Grid.Column="0" Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                        Text="{Binding Display}" FontSize="30" 
                        />
                    <TextBlock 
                        Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                        Text="{Binding Length}" FontSize="30"
                        />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <ListBoxItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="0" Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                    Text="2014-01-24 23:00:00" FontSize="30"
                    />
                <TextBlock 
                    Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                    Text="00:00" FontSize="30"
                    />
            </Grid>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
```

Result:

[image]

Item in designer:

[image]

Comment: Columns defined                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change HorizontalContentAligment to Strech - to fill the space with your item, by default it's set to the left:

```
<ListBox Name="myList">
  <ListBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
       <Grid>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="2014-01-24 23:00:00" FontSize="30"/>
          <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="00:00" FontSize="30"/>
        </Grid>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

You can also set Property of ItemContainerStyle:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
           <TextBlock Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Display}" FontSize="30"/>
           <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Length}" FontSize="30"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

 <ListBoxItem>
    <Grid>
      <TextBlock Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="2014-01-24 23:00:00" FontSize="30"/>
      <TextBlock Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="00:00" FontSize="30"/>
    </Grid>
  </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

In case you have only two items, one aligned to left, one to right - I've removed Colums. Although they help to manage the content, align it and they also will be helpful if you need to wrap text and/or perform more operations on it.

Comment: Big thanks! <ListBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"> in <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> stretch TextBlock in ListBoxItem and HorizontalAlignment start work.

Comment: @AlexandrSulimov Then don't forget to mark the answer as a solution (green tick besides) - if it solved your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it :

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBlock 
         Grid.Column="0" Padding="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
         Text="{Binding Display}" FontSize="30" 
         />
    <TextBlock 
         Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
         Text="{Binding Length}" FontSize="30"
         />
</Grid>
```

This will give 75% width to the first column and remaining 25% to the second column.

If you want the first and second columns to dynamically change width according to the content then you can give one width as "Auto" and the other no width property (or Width="*") which means it will take the remaining area as the column width.

Answer (score 0):

I would take Alexandr Sulimov solution. I made some improvements. I think it is the best way to do it.

```
 <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Padding="10" Text="{Binding Display}" FontSize="30" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Length}" FontSize="30" />
 </Grid>
```

Comment: But it won't work without <ListBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">. That's not the problem with Columns - by default Items ContentAligment is set to Left and it doesn't fill whole width.

Comment: I am on Linux and I cant test it so you can be right, but I am pretty sure this would work. It is a classic behavior, I used it a lot of time on windowsphone.

Comment: Just check on google you [have right in WPF](http://wpftutorial.net/StrechListBoxItem.html). Now, I want to try it myself. For now, kudo for you.

Comment: Columns was also my first thought :)